# How can i remove different strings from one string?

Tags: java, string, replace

I've been searching for a while but other answers are quiet different to what im trying to do.
I'm trying to delete prepositions from a string but i wonder if there is any way to delete them without doing it one by one like i'm doing right now:
(I'm trying to delete spanish prepositions like (de, del, el, la))

```
String content = "Martinez de Rodríguez, Rosa
Lothbrok, Ragnar
Skywalker, Anakin
Ronaldo, Cristiano
Del campo Lopez, Antonio";
String withoutPreposition = content.replace("de ", ""); 
System.out.println(withoutPreposition);
```

Once i do that the result is:

```
Martinez Rodríguez, Rosa
Lothbrok, Ragnar
Skywalker, Anakin
Ronaldo, Cristiano
Del campo Lopez, Antonio
```

Could i delete all prepositions at once or i need to do it one by one?

Comment: You can try to use regex and set of alternatives.

Comment: Use String's replaceAll method

Comment: @AG replace replaces all anyway.

Comment: You can use ```replaceAll``` method on your string with regex ```(de|del|el|la)```: ```content.replaceAll("(de|del|el|la)\\s", "")```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to use regex

```
stringToReplaceIn.replaceAll("de |del |el |la ","");
```